# XSLT : compare date timezone

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT.

How to compare the date strings in XSLT and output the result?

Below is my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dates>
    <date1>2003-09-15T16:53:22.000-07:00</date1>
    <date2>2003-09-15T16:53:23.000-07:00</date2>
</dates>
```

Below is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:variable name="date1" select="/dates/date1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="date2" select="/dates/date2"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="$date1  &gt;  $date2">
            date1 is greater
        </xsl:if>
        
        <xsl:if test="$date1  =  $date2">
            both dates are equal
        </xsl:if>
        
        <xsl:if test="$date1  &lt;=  $date2">
            date1 is lesser than date2
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now in XSLT I want to compare the above dates, so is it possible in XSLT 1.0 to compare (greater,lesser, equals) the dates?

I believe in XSLT 1.0 it's not possible. Can it be done in XSLT 2.0?

(In my current study project, I have used XSLT 1.0, so please suggest answer in XSLT 1.0 if possible).

Comment: If available, this can be done easily with the [EXSLT function `date:seconds`](http://exslt.org/date/functions/seconds/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in XSLT 1.0, you must first convert the given dateTimes to numerical values and equalize them to a common time zone.

In the following stylesheet, each dateTime is converted to the number of seconds elapsed since noon UTC of November 24, 4714 BC - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="dates">
    <xsl:variable name="date1">
        <xsl:call-template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
            <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="date1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:variable name="date2">
        <xsl:call-template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
            <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="date2" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <result>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$date1 &lt; $date2">date1 occurs earlier than date2</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$date1 = $date2">the two dates are concurrent</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$date1 &gt; $date2">date1 occurs later than date2</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime"/>

    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($dateTime, 'T')" />
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-after($dateTime, 'T')" />

    <xsl:variable name="local-time" select="substring($time, 1, string-length($time) - 6)" />
    <xsl:variable name="offset" select="substring-after($time, $local-time)" />

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)" />

    <xsl:variable name="hour" select="substring($local-time, 1, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="minute" select="substring($local-time, 4, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="second" select="substring($local-time, 7)" />

    <xsl:variable name="offset-sign" select="1 - 2 * starts-with($offset, '-')" />
    <xsl:variable name="offset-hour" select="substring($offset, 2, 2) * $offset-sign" />
    <xsl:variable name="offset-minute" select="substring($offset, 5, 2) * $offset-sign" />

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="jd" select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />

    <xsl:value-of select="86400*$jd + 3600*$hour + 60*$minute + $second - 3600*$offset-hour - 60*$offset-minute" />
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<dates>
    <date1>2003-09-15T16:53:22.000-07:00</date1>
    <date2>2003-09-15T17:53:22.000-06:00</date2>
</dates>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>the two dates are concurrent</result>
```

Comment: very much happy for the solution, as i can see that you have considered 365 days in a year. i have question will this works even in leap year (366 days) and in day light saving.?

Comment: "*i can see that you have considered 365 days in a year*" You should look at the entire expression `365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400)`. That's what accounts for leap years. -- As for day light saving, it's irrelevant here: the dateTime includes an offset from UTC; if day light saving was in effect, the offset will reflect that.